# Error in C sine(x) Approximating

Tags: c, series

I am trying to Calculate the value of Sin(x) using taylor series ie:x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!
What I tried is this code but it sort of giving me error!

```
int n;
int factorial;
float sum=0;
float angle;
int sign=1;
int i,j;

printf("Please Enter angle in degrees:\n");
scanf("%f",&angle);
angle=angle*3.14/180;

printf("Please Enter Number of terms:\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
    factorial=1;
    for (j=1;j<=(2*i-1);j++)
    factorial=factorial*j;
sum=sum+sign*(pow(angle,j)/factorial);
sign*=-1;
}
printf("Sum up to %d terms is %f",n,sum);
```

Comment: By chance, do you use python?

Comment: You really should be doing all of this in floating point, preferably double.  In particular, you're passing integer arguments to functions that expect double, and relying in the compiler to cast the arguments for you based on the information in the function declaration.  It's a lot clearer to make the data types explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Off by 1

`j` is 1 too great

```
// sum=sum+sign*(pow(angle,j)/factorial);
sum=sum+sign*(pow(angle,j-1)/factorial);
```

---

Suggest a better approximation of pi

```
#define MY_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
// angle=angle*3.14/180;
angle *= MY_PI/180;
```

No real value here in using `float`  Consider `double`.  If code wants to stay with `float`, then use `float` functions like `powf(angle,j)` - note the `f`.

---

Tip: Rather than recompute the factorial of the term starting from 1 each time, continue from the previous term.

```
//psuedo code
term = -x*x/(2i)/(2i+1)*previous_term
```

---

```
  double sum = 0.0;
  double x2 = x_radians * x_radians;
  double term = x_radians;
  for (unsigned i = 1; i <= terms; i++) {
    sum += term;
    term *= -x2 / ((2 * i) * (2 * i + 1));
  }
```